# got AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute while importing global variable from another file

Tags: python, import, global-variables, attributeerror

I have two python files like this:

```
# first.py
global x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 'test_var'
```

and:

```
# second.py
import first
class XX(object):
    @staticmethod
    def print_x():
        print first.x
```

I run this script:

```
import second
second.XX.print_x()
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: For one, `XX.print_x()` shouldn't work, it should be `second.XX.print_x()`

Comment: @Natecat you are right! my typo!

Answer (score 1):

The code in `first.py` never runs because it isn't your entry point and the code isn't directly called, meaning x is never defined. Use first.py as your entry point or put the declaration of x into a method that you call before trying to access it.

Comment: To add on to this, OP hasn't understood the `if __name__ == "__main__"` trick. I suggest inserting `print __name__` at the beginning of `first.py`, and seeing the difference between running `first.py` directly and the other script.